# Clickable areas inside image

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Searching for some design suggestions. I am using Angular (at least trying).
Suppose I have a clickable areas defined like this with backgrounded image (more than two):

```
<div id="clicable0">
        <div class="area1" data-ng-click="jump('v1')"></div>
        <div class="area2" data-ng-click="jump('v2')"></div>
        ...
        <img src="img1.jpg">
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#clicable0 .area1 { top:100px; left:100px; }
#clicable0 .area2 { top:100px; left:200px; }
```

The above example works just fine, but I would see this more like general component (directive?) where I could do more on the Angular and Javascript. What would be your suggestions to 'opaque' this with some Angular futures?
Thanks.

Comment: huh? is it me or is this question a bit vague?

Comment: hmm. Let me edit a bit.

Comment: Do you want to use an image map?

Comment: an image map, in 2013 :p ?

Comment: something like this :)